# How do I disable the STS Dashboard in STS 3.6.0 and Greater

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

In the newer versions of STS, 3.6.0 and above, there is no longer an option to turn off the Spring Dashboard, does anyone know how to achieve this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just closing Dashboard and then seeing if it stays closed when you re-start STS? There was supposed a fix in 3.6.0 that made the Dashboard stay gone once you closed it.

By my observations it does *not* work as of 3.6.2, I suspect it is a regression or there is something else wrong with the fix. Here's the bug report: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3824 - you'll see that I commented there adding steps to reproduce the bug in 3.6.2

**Update:** A new bug has been opened for the regression in 3.6.2: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3935

Comment: I've tried closing it, it always comes back, I'm currently on 3.6.2 and experiencing the issue...

Comment: If I use a fresh STS 3.6.2 and a new and empty workspace, the dashboard appears automatically. When I close it and start STS, it doesn't come back. Therefore the behavior that you describe sound like a bug that appears only in some situations. Do you use an old workspace?

Comment: I created a new workspace when I downloaded Eclipse Luna 4.4, since then I installed STS 3.6.0 and then upgraded to 3.6.2, now I'm stuck with Dashboard :)

Comment: See my comment on the bug (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3824?focusedCommentId=103630&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-103630); it happens with a brand new 3.6.2 and brand new workspace.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the JIRA, can you update your answer to say this is indeed a bug and I will mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: If someone hitting this problem, could please take a look at the bug report (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3935) and add some information... I am not able to reproduce the bug as of yet (works for me), so something about what triggers the bug is missing and without knowing what it is we won't be able to fix it. I added some info about things to check in the bug report. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I have 3.6.3 SR1 and this works now. I closed the window, re-opened STS, and no dashboard.